# Redirect url magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, seo

I did a migration between Oscommerce and magento and now, to not lose our work with SEO I want to redirect the olds Url to the news Urls in magento, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can add all your URLs to the Magento URL re-write table either manually or by importing them. There are a number of modules that will allow you to import an list of urls for 301 redirects

I you do not want to do that you can always manually create 301 redirects in your htaccess file.

Comment: How can I add it to the .htaccess ? I had to add every url I want to change?

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use Url rewrite managment of magento because It has lots of data entry then you can manually add 301 url redirect rule in `.htaccess` file here is the sample code for that , please put path after baseurl.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 #301 redirect
 redirect 301 /oldurl/ /newurl.html    
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with .htaccess, you could use the Magento admin setting "**Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management**", that could set url redirect conveniently.

After save setting, you need "Refresh the **Catalog URL Rewrites** Index" in **System > Index Management** to see the effect.